# Variant of integration form for delta function $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |k| \exp(ikx)dk$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I want to simplify the integration
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |k| \exp(ikx)dk$$ 
$$=\int_0^\infty k \cos(kx)dk$$ using some kind of delta function.

Delta function has integration form, such as
$$\delta(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ikx} dk$$
$$         =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \cos{(kx)} dk$$
Also, the derivative of delta function has integration form,
$$\delta'(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ike^{ikx} dk$$
$$         =-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\infty k\sin{(kx)} dk$$

All integration looks very similar. So, I think the first integration can be written using delta function.

If you know how to do this, please tell me.

Comment: Use integration by parts, not distributions

Comment: If I use integration by parts, then this integration do not converge.

Comment: @Fakemistake And how do you deal with the divergent intermediate form?

Comment: And I do not really understand the downvotes. This is a perfectly fine question, well-phrased and an own attempt is clearly visible.

Comment: I would generate the k by a derivative with respect to x

Comment: @mrtaurho The problem is that the OP doesn't seem to know how to handle distributions and their Fourier transforms correctly. The Fourier transform of $sign(x)$ is $C pv(1/k)$, thus the Fourier transform of $|x|$ is $A fp(1/k^2)+B\delta(k)$

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly question. What's the meaning of the notation of $Cpv$ and $fp$?

Comment: @eiru It's not silly: It's interesting.

Comment: No downvote from me! I haven’t seen the boundary of integration, so I thought you want an antiderivative. Excuse me for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty k \cos(kx)dk=\frac{d}{dx}{\rm Im}\,\int_0^\infty e^{ikx}\,dk=\frac{d}{dx}{\cal P}x^{-1},$$
in view of the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem)
$$\int_0^\infty e^{ikx}\,dk=\pi\delta(x)+i{\cal P}x^{-1},$$
where ${\cal P}$ denotes the principal value.

Comment: You need to clarify for the OP in what sense those integrals converge, and it takes 2 lines to find the Fourier transform of $sign(x)$