# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(iqy')dy' \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|\exp(ik(y-y'))dk$ in 2 way give different results

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I have integration whose result change depending on the way of calculation.

I want to compute the integration below
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(iqy')dy' \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|\exp(ik(y-y'))dk$$

If integration is conducted in the order $y'$, $k$

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(iqy')dy' \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|\exp(ik(y-y'))dk\\
&=2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|\exp(iky)\delta(q-k) dk\\
&=2\pi |q|\exp(iqy) dk
\end{align}$$

However, if integration is conducted in the order $k$, $y'$ with [the formula](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/absT.php), $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dk |k|\exp(ik(y-y'))=-\frac{1}{(y-y')^2}$, it returns different result.
$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(iqy')dy' \int_{-\infty}^\infty |k|\exp(ik(y-y'))dk\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp(iqy')}{(y-y')^2} dy'\\
\end{align}$$
The integration of latter case does not converge. This is the apparent contradiction.

I have asked the simplified form of the Fourier transform of $|x|$ in stack exchange [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288131/variant-of-integration-form-for-delta-function-frac12-int-infty-infty) and some people point out my treatment of Fourier transform is incorrect in the view of convergence. However I cannot understand the problem. Maybe there is relationship why Integration fail here.

Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake of link. I correct it.

Comment: No problem. Regarding the convergence: when working with distributions (such as the Delta Distribution) the notion of convergence changes somewhat. Not being an expert in this field, I cannot really answer your question but I wanted to point this issue out.

Comment: The single integrals over $k$ and over $y'$ both diverge. In terms of distributions, you're computing the Fourier transform of $|k|$ followed by the inverse Fourier transform. It does make sense that your last integral gives $|q|$ (ignoring the normalization constant, the $e^{i q y}$ factor and the lost minus sign), but this is just a symbolic notation for the Fourier transform of a certain distribution related to the function $1/x^2$.