# $\int_0^\infty k \cos(kx)dk=\frac{d}{dx}{\cal P}x^{-1}$ is wrong, but I don't know why.

Tags: integration

I have asked the way of integration before [at here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288131/variant-of-integration-form-for-delta-function-frac12-int-infty-infty) .
The integration which got best answer is below.
$$\int_0^\infty k \cos(kx)dk=\frac{d}{dx}{\cal P}x^{-1}$$

However, I notice that at $x=0$, $k \cos(kx) = k$ and so, the right side term, 
$\frac{d}{dx}{\cal P}x^{-1}$ should be positive at x=0 although it is $-\infty$ now.

My question is what is the hidden mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those integrals converge only in the sense of distributions, you can't just plug $x=0$ and deduce something about the sign, in particular the distributional derivative $\frac{d}{dx}{\cal P}x^{-1}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log |x|$ is not the same as $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ at all :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty e^{-k^2/n^2} k dk= +\infty$$
indicates that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty n e^{-x^2n^2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log |x|=\lim_{n \to \infty}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \log |x|(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}n e^{-x^2n^2})  dx = +\infty$$

---

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log |x|$ follows from

$$\int_0^\infty e^{ikx}\,dk=\lim_{r \to 0}\int_0^\infty e^{-rk} e^{ikx}\,dk =\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r-ix} =\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{d}{dx} i\log(x+ir)\\=\frac{d}{dx}(i \log |x|-\pi 1_{x < 0})= \pi \delta(x)+i\frac{d}{dx} \log |x|$$ so that $$\int_0^\infty k \cos(kx)dk=\frac{d}{dx}\Im\int_0^\infty e^{ikx}\,dk=\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \log |x|$$

Comment: What is this $fp$? Why does it yield this funny $\phi'(0) x 1_{|x|<1}$ term?

Comment: It is the distribution I defined (finite part)

Comment: So you just made up the name? Then I think you should indeed explain why it takes this form.

Comment: So the $1_{|x|<1}$ is really $1_{|x|<\epsilon}$ for whatever $\epsilon$ you want, since it takes the same value regardless? That's not obvious to someone inexperienced with these matters from your answer either. Or if I'm wrong then it's even less obvious why $1$ comes into play as the cutoff...

Comment: $\log |x|$ is even and $pv(1/x)$ is defined as its derivative thus it is odd and for any $\psi$ even with $\psi(0) = 1$ then $<pv(1/x),\psi> = 0$ and $<pv(1/x),\phi-\phi(0) \psi>= \int \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)\psi(x)}{x}dx$. For the second derivative it is the same idea

Comment: I think the representation might just not be adding anything here, the point is just that the mapping $\phi \mapsto \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty k \cos(kx) \phi(x) dx dk$ is the distributional derivative of $\mathcal{P}(1/x)$. You could simplify this expression in all sorts of different ways; I guess a perfectly good way would be as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|x|) \phi''(x) dx$. Do any such representations really have anything to do with the question? In particular, can we use a representation to explain the sign of values of the functional and if so how?

Comment: That $<|k|, e^{-k^2/n^2}>$ is large positive means $<-fp(1/x^2), n e^{-x^2 n^2}>$ is large positive, which is due to my $\phi(0)$ term or to your negative sign of $\log |x|$ around $0$